# Gmail refuses to send mails. How to solve it without 2-Step Verification

Tags: python, gmail

So I send

```
import smtplib

server= smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
server.login('mail_from@gmail.com', 'my_pass')
msg='hello'
server.sendmail('mail_from@gmail.com','mail_to@gmail.com',msg)
server.quit()
```

I get

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
> raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

Once I did this way
Account -> Allow less secure app -> ON
and it was OK.
Recently they disabled the "Allow less secure app" feature.

Is there any way to keep sending mails?

Comment: The title of the duplicate is different but the problem is the same.

Comment: I see no resemblance or duplication. Absolutely different problems. My problem - blocking the mail on Gmail server side by disabling  'Allow less secure app'. No matter what language you choose - Python, Java, C, C# - you'll get the same result. Till the  'Allow less secure app' problem I sent mails successfully.

Comment: Your `msg` is not a valid RFC5322 message. The "Allow less secure app" is separately a duplicate; let me find that and add it.

Comment: May be. But it fails before server.sendmail. I fails on server.login stage.

Comment: To check it I've changed he msg - 
msg = EmailMessage() msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
msg['From'] = 'me'
msg['To'] = 'you'  
The same result.

Comment: The others posts answers - enable 2-step verification - doesn't suit me. 
They demand my phone number to involve it in the verification. It's too much.